# Razor if condition difference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Why is the second if statement incorrect? note that I attempted to make it a single line.

[image: Correct If Condition]

[image]

thanks

**After Andrei Andrushkevich suggestion**, red code. Tree and ul are red/squiggled. Plus the function param is red and all references in the blurred code is red.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `@:` sequence indicates that the **entire line** of content that follows should be treated as a content block.

So `@if (condition) { @: Some content }` won't work because the last bracket is interpreted as content and another ending `}` will be expected.

For single line conditions you can use the `<text>` tag:

`@if (condition) { <text>Some content</text> }`

Answer (score 1):

Remove first symbol "@" from the second condition.

Comment: Now the `</ul>` is complaining with red squiggle line "Unmatched closing tag". Also, other code on the page turns red.

Comment: you don't need to use '@' after "}", and try to use <text><ul></text>